# FPDF barcode without human readable text

Tags: barcode, fpdf, code39

Using FPDF and FPDI library, is it possible to print barcode without human readable text? I am using Code39 library but I cannot find anywhere to disable the text.

Comment: This is extremely broad. Can you show code examples of what you've done so far? An image of what you have versus what you want also would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the color to the background color the text won't show. That is the only solution I have found.
$pdf->SetTextColor(255, 255, 255);//white text